# Filtering null values from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

i built a back end server API using nodejs and linked it to an existing database i have ( that is full of null values ) then linked the backend server to my front end react native project to show the data on my screen
so am trying to filtre out the null values so my app shows only the ones with value ( a title a an img and an excerpt everytime ) as you can see in the screen below i only get one or the other and sometimes nothing at all.
so i there a way to do this using axios or using some sort of filter function

here is the code i used in my hook : 
useArticle.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import articles from "../api/articles";
import axios from "axios";
export default () => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const loadApi = async () => {
    // wait for a reponse to get back once it does with some data we asign that data to the reponse variable
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://192.168.1.2:3001/articles");
      //console.log(response.data);
      setDocs(response.data.data);
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
  // bad code
  //searchApi("pasta");
  useEffect(() => {
    loadApi();
  }, []);

  return [loadApi, docs, errorMessage];
};
```

here is the code i used on TrackCreateScreen.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from "react-native";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import useResults from "../hooks/useResults";
import ResutlsList from "../components/ResultsList";
import ResutlsListVer from "../components/ResultsListVer";
import useArticles from "../hooks/useArticles";
const TrackCreateScreen = () => {
  const [loadApi, docs, errorMessage] = useArticles();
  /*
  const filterNull = (docs) => {
    return docs.filter((doc) => {
      if ((doc.title = ".")) return doc.title;
    });
  };
  console.log(filterNull(docs)); */

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={docs}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#abc123", padding: 10, margin: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              {item.title}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>{item.excerpt}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    //flex: 1, // when ever we have a content that is being cut off or expanding off the screen
  },
  Text: {
    fontSize: 32,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
export default TrackCreateScreen;
```

Am using express for the back end server and my code looks like this  :

```
app.get("/articles", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    //aritcles with null values
    const articles = await Article.find();
    const articlesResponse = articles.filter((item) => {
      let isValidObject = true; // item is an article  it has title img excerpt keys
      for (let key in item) {
        if (!item[key]) isValidObject = false;
      }
      return isValidObject;
    });
    res.json(articlesResponse);
    //res.json(articles);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(422).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

and on my server.js file i call the articleRouter like this : app.use("/articles", articleRouter);

[image: A SCREEN SHOT OF THE APP WITH NULL VALUES]

Comment: Simply use `array.filter(item => item !== null)` in the backend you built before it returns to your frontend?

Comment: where exactly should i  use it?

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Assume you use the Express framework, here's some quick code you for you:

```
app.get('/articles', async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
       // assume you fetch from the database which contains null values here
       const withNullList = await fetchFromDbWithNullValues;

       // filter the null values here
       const articlesResponse = withNullList.filter(item => item !== null)

       res.send(articlesResponse);
   } catch (e) {
       //handle error
   }
})
```

If you want to filter out the articles which has any key with `null` value you can do this.

```
// filter the article items which any of its key is null here
const articlesResponse = withNullList.filter(item => {
    let isValidObject = true
    for (let key in item) {
       if (!item[key])
          isValidObject = false;
    }
    return isValidObject
})
```

------ more updates ------

Here's an example article list from your comment:

```
[
  { 
    "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c2", 
    "excerpt": "The shooting of Ahmaud Arbery.", 
    "img": null, 
    "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad", 
    "title": null, 
  }, 
  { 
    "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c3", 
    "excerpt": null, 
    "img": null, 
    "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad", 
    "title": null, 
  }
]
```

Say if you want to filter out objects that any of `excerpt` / `img` / `title` is `null`:

```
const articlesResponse = withNullList.filter(item => {
    let isValidObject = true
    if (!item.excerpt || !item.img || !item.title) // change this line according to what you want
        isValidObject = false;
    return isValidObject // if true, means we want this object, false means filter this object
})
```

Comment: i edited my post and added a sample of my express code

Comment: i used this `app.get("/articles", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //aritcles with null values
    const articles = await Article.find();
    const articlesResponse = articles.filter((item) => item !== null);
    res.json(articlesResponse);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(422).send(err.message);
  }` 
i still get null values how ever

Comment: Are you sure the articles returned contain null values? Or is article an object and only the data part is null? E.g. { id: 1, value: null }, then you have to check whether article.value is null instead of whether article is null

Comment: yes article is an object and some fields are null how do i filter out all the fields that have null values and just leave the only ones who has values in all the fields 
here is a sample :
`Object {
      "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c2",
      "excerpt": "The shooting of Ahmaud Arbery.",
      "img": null,
      "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad",
      "title": null,
    },
    Object {
      "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c3",
      "excerpt": null,
      "img": null,
      "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad",
      "title": null,
    },`

Comment: so you want do filter out article objects with what condition? when `img` is null?, or when there is any key with a null value?

Comment: where there is any key with a null value so i can you the end points from the back end server on my front end react native app , its a news app and having an image with no title would make the app unusable

Comment: is something like that possible or i should just find a way to clean the data from the source? @Andus